# How to display WP custom class in before in nav?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to display icons in WP nav by using CSS class form menu section from backed.
[image]

I am using the following code to display nav but i dont know ho to call this class in link_before

```
<?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'menu'              => 'primary',
                                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                                'depth'             => 3,
                                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                'link_before'    => '<i class="wht_to_do_here"></i>',
                                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                            );
                        ?>
```

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Class from Back end is for the `<li>` tag. So first we need to remove that from `<li>`.

To remove it from `<li>`, add following code to your theme's **functions.php** :

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'remove_class_from_li',10, 2);

function remove_class_from_li($class, $item){
    $css_class = get_post_meta($item->ID, '_menu_item_classes', true);
    $class = array_diff($class,$css_class);
    return $class;
}
```

Now we need to modify its anchor tag to add `<i>` tag into it. So for that add below code to your theme's **functions.php** :

```
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_class_before', 10, 4);

function add_class_before($item_output, $item, $depth, $args){
    $css_class = get_post_meta($item->ID, '_menu_item_classes', true);
    if(is_array($css_class)){
        $class = implode(' ', $css_class);
        if($class){
            $args->link_before = '<i class="'.$class.'"></i>';
        }
    }
    $atts = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    return $item_output;
}
```

As we have modified everything, you might not need to add `link_before` parameter in `wp_nav_menu` function. So your `wp_nav_menu` will now look like :

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'              => 'primary',
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 3,
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
?>
```

It's done :)

**NOTE :** You can also do it by making your own [menu walker](http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/).

**Caution :** By doing above method, it will apply to all menu and if you do not want to apply it to all menu thn probably you have to add condition with menu location.

Comment: Thank you so much.
This is what i want and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class through use of jQuery .addClass method or use css .nav::before{content: "\f015"; font-family: 'FontAwesome';} method add this class in your css.

Comment: I need icons for all nav but using .nav::before{content: "\f015"; font-family: 'FontAwesome';} only gives for single nav.

Comment: You can use .nav:nth-child(number of navigation) and repeat numbers of require navigation class with icons content